# Draw with canvas Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawing

For now I want the canvas to just draw a color.

```
public class AndroidTentaTestActivity extends Activity {

    private Bitmap bm;
    private Canvas c;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Config.ARGB_8888);
        c = new Canvas(bm);
        c.drawARGB(100, 0, 0, 150);
    }
}
```

The code above is what I´ve written so far that obviously does not work. I suspect the Bitmap is somehow not connected to what I am doing but I don´t know how to fix it. How do I?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  "Somehow not connected".  What do you mean?  Unless you display the bitmap somewhere, of course you are not going to see it.

Comment: The canvas does not show so the entire screen is black(on my s2 i use for debugging). How do I display the canvas?

Comment: You still have not explained WHAT you are trying to do.  You cannot "display" a canvas.  A canvas is just a holder for drawing calls on a bitmap.  Unless you draw on the canvas of a bitmap that is part of your UI, you will not see anything.

Comment: I want to make the screen blue. Then how do I make the bitmap part of my UI?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a canvas for this?  I think you need to start with some "Hello World" examples.  Making the screen blue is very simple, it's first day in school.  Create an XML layout and set the background colour of the root view to blue.  Then use setContentView in onCreate() to inflate the XML into your UI. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: Later on I need to draw different objects in the canvas. I am not an newbie to programming and I have done the hello world examples. For know it´s about making the canvas any color but my goal is not that simple.

Comment: OK, see this nicely commented example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/ExampleofhowtowriteacustomsubclassofView.htm

Answer (score 1):

Change the desired color in mPaint.setColor().

```
public class AndroidTentaTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MyView mv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mv = new MyView(this);
    mv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    setContentView(mv);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
}

private Paint mPaint;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

public class MyView extends View {

    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    Context context;

    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        context = c;
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 1;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        //showDialog();
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);

        mX = x;
        mY = y;

    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
          //  mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);                       //2,2.old values

            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rect);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(ll.getWidth(),ll.getHeight() , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bg);
canvas.drawARGB(200, 0, 225, 255);
ll.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bg));
```